# MS Publisher: Horizontal guides from master page only appearing on left hand pages

Tags: microsoft-publisher

I'm working in MS Publisher 2016 (fully updated), and I've created a two page Master containing a series of horizontal and vertical guides (I'm designing playing card mockups).  All of the guides appear on left hand pages in the main document, but the horizontal guides don't appear (or function) on the right hand pages.  I've toggled the Guides off and back on again on the View tab and nothing changes.  I've done some searching online and can't see evidence this is a widespread problem, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I've also tried removing the guides and readding them, same result.

Comment: If it was me.. I'll manually build a rectangular ruler-like shape with to 'align' the objects on both pages. This was the trick I used in powerpoint when I don't want to depend on the gridlines as guide. || mind sharing how your screen look like for us to reproduce the effect/problem ?

Comment: I haven't diagnosed the original problem, but I've rebuilt the guides on the individual pages, and then just copy and pasted the pages when I need new ones.  I'm still quite puzzled by the original problem.